# Make a total vector for three vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy

We have a class that have three functions called(Bdisk, Bhalo,and BX).
all of these functions accept arrays (e.g. shape (1000))not matrices (e.g. shape (2,1000)).
I want to get the total of all these functions( total= Bdisk + Bhalo+BX), total these all functions give the magnetic field in all three components (B_r, B_phi, B_z) for thousand coordinate points (r, phi, z).

the code is here:

```html
import numpy as np
import logging
import warnings
import gmf
signum = lambda x: (x < 0.) * -1. + (x >= 0) * 1.
pi = np.pi

#Class with analytical functions that describe the GMF according to the model of JF12  
class GMF(object):
    
    def __init__(self): # self:is automatically set to reference the newly created object that needs to be initialized  
 self.Rsun = -8.5   # position of the sun along the x axis  in kpc 
############################################################################
 # Disk Parameters
############################################################################
 self.bring, self.bring_unc = 0.1,0.1 # floats, field strength in ring at 3 kpc < r < 5 kpc
 self.hdisk, self.hdisk_unc = 0.4, 0.03 # float, disk/halo transition height 
 self.wdisk, self.wdisk_unc = 0.27,0.08 #  floats, transition width
 self.b  = np.array([0.1,3.,-0.9,-0.8,-2.0,-4.2,0.,2.7]) # (8,1)-dim np.arrays, field strength of spiral arms at 5 kpc
 self.b_unc = np.array([1.8,0.6,0.8,0.3,0.1,0.5,1.8,1.8]) # uncertainty 
 self.rx  = np.array([5.1,6.3,7.1,8.3,9.8,11.4,12.7,15.5])#  (8,1)-dim np.array,dividing lines of spiral lines coordinates of neg. x-axes that intersect with arm
 self.idisk = 11.5 * pi/180.  #  float, spiral arms pitch angle
#############################################################################
 # Halo Parameters
#############################################################################
 self.Bn, self.Bn_unc = 1.4,0.1 #  floats, field strength northern halo
 self.Bs, self.Bs_unc = -1.1,0.1 #  floats, field strength southern halo
 self.rn, self.rn_unc = 9.22,0.08 # floats, transition radius south, lower limit 
 self.rs, self.rs_unc = 16.7,0. # transition radius south, lower limit
 self.whalo, self.whalo_unc = 0.2,0.12 # floats, transition width
 self.z0, self.z0_unc  = 5.3, 1.6 # floats, vertical scale height
##############################################################################
 # Out of plaxe or "X" component Parameters
##############################################################################
 self.BX0, self.BX_unc = 4.6,0.3 # floats,  field strength at origin
 self.ThetaX0, self.ThetaX0_unc = 49. * pi/180., pi/180. # elev. angle at z = 0, r > rXc
 self.rXc, self.rXc_unc = 4.8, 0.2 # floats, radius where thetaX = thetaX0
 self.rX, self.rX_unc = 2.9, 0.1 # floats, exponential scale length
 # striated field
 self.gamma, self.gamma_unc = 2.92,0.14 # striation and/or rel. elec. number dens. rescaling
 return 
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
    # Transition function given by logistic function eq.5
##################################################################################
    def L(self,z,h,w): 
  
 if np.isscalar(z):
     z = np.array([z]) # scalar or numpy array with positions (height above disk, z; distance from center, r)
 ones = np.ones(z.shape[0])
 return 1./(ones + np.exp(-2. *(np.abs(z)- h)/w))    
####################################################################################
 # return distance from center for angle phi of logarithmic spiral
 # r(phi) = rx * exp(b * phi) as np.array
####################################################################################
    def r_log_spiral(self,phi):
  
 if np.isscalar(phi): #Returns True if the type of num is a scalar type.
     phi = np.array([phi])
 ones = np.ones(phi.shape[0])

 # self.rx.shape = 8
 # phi.shape = p
 # then result is given as (8,p)-dim array, each row stands for one rx
    # vstack : Take a sequence of arrays and stack them vertically to make a single array
 # tensordot(a, b, axes=2):Compute tensor dot product along specified axes for arrays >=1D.
 result = np.tensordot(self.rx , np.exp((phi - 3.*pi*ones) / np.tan(pi/2. - self.idisk)),axes = 0)
 result = np.vstack((result, np.tensordot(self.rx , np.exp((phi - pi*ones) / np.tan(pi/2. - self.idisk)),axes = 0) ))
 result = np.vstack((result, np.tensordot(self.rx , np.exp((phi + pi*ones) / np.tan(pi/2. - self.idisk)),axes = 0) ))
 return np.vstack((result, np.tensordot(self.rx , np.exp((phi + 3.*pi*ones) / np.tan(pi/2. - self.idisk)),axes = 0) ))    
#############################################################################################
 # Disk component in galactocentric cylindrical coordinates (r,phi,z)
#############################################################################################
    def Bdisk(self,r,phi,z):
 # Bdisk is purely azimuthal (toroidal) with the field strength b_ring
 """ 
 r: N-dim np.array, distance from origin in GC cylindrical coordinates, is in kpc
 z: N-dim np.array, height in kpc in GC cylindrical coordinates
 phi:N-dim np.array, polar angle in GC cylindircal coordinates, in radian 
 Bdisk: (3,N)-dim np.array with (r,phi,z) components of disk field for each coordinate tuple
 |Bdisk|: N-dim np.array, absolute value of Bdisk for each coordinate tuple
 """
 if (not r.shape[0] == phi.shape[0]) and (not z.shape[0] == phi.shape[0]):
     warnings.warn("List do not have equal shape! returning -1", RuntimeWarning)
     return -1
    # Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros.
 Bdisk = np.zeros((3,r.shape[0])) # Bdisk vector in r, phi, z   
 ones  = np.ones(r.shape[0])
 r_center = (r >= 3.) & (r < 5.1)
 r_disk  = (r >= 5.1) & (r <= 20.)
 Bdisk[1,r_center] = self.bring

 # Determine in which arm we are
 # this is done for each coordinate individually
 if np.sum(r_disk):
     rls = self.r_log_spiral(phi[r_disk])

     rls = np.abs(rls - r[r_disk])
     arms = np.argmin(rls, axis = 0) % 8
        # The magnetic spiral defined at r=5 kpc and fulls off as 1/r ,the field direction is given by:
     Bdisk[0,r_disk] = np.sin(self.idisk)* self.b[arms] * (5. / r[r_disk]) 
     Bdisk[1,r_disk] = np.cos(self.idisk)* self.b[arms] * (5. / r[r_disk])

 Bdisk  *= (ones - self.L(z,self.hdisk,self.wdisk)) # multiplied by L 
 return Bdisk, np.sqrt(np.sum(Bdisk**2.,axis = 0)) # the Bdisk, the normalization 
    # axis=0 : sum over index 0(row)
    # axis=1 : sum over index 1(columns) 
##############################################################################################
 # Halo component 
###############################################################################################
    def Bhalo(self,r,z): 
    # Bhalo is purely azimuthal (toroidal), i.e. has only a phi component
 if (not r.shape[0] == z.shape[0]):
     warnings.warn("List do not have equal shape! returning -1", RuntimeWarning)
     return -1
    
 Bhalo = np.zeros((3,r.shape[0])) # Bhalo vector in r, phi, z  rows: r, phi and z component
 ones  = np.ones(r.shape[0])
 m = ( z != 0. )
    # SEE equation 6.
 Bhalo[1,m] = np.exp(-np.abs(z[m])/self.z0) * self.L(z[m], self.hdisk, self.wdisk) * \
   ( self.Bn * (ones[m] - self.L(r[m], self.rn, self.whalo)) * (z[m] > 0.) \
   + self.Bs * (ones[m] - self.L(r[m], self.rs, self.whalo)) * (z[m] < 0.) )
 return Bhalo , np.sqrt(np.sum(Bhalo**2.,axis = 0))
    
##############################################################################################
 # BX component (OUT OF THE PLANE) 
###############################################################################################
    def BX(self,r,z):
 
 #BX is purely  ASS  and poloidal, i.e. phi component = 0 
 if (not r.shape[0] == z.shape[0]):
     warnings.warn("List do not have equal shape! returning -1", RuntimeWarning)
     return -1

 BX= np.zeros((3,r.shape[0])) # BX vector in r, phi, z  rows: r, phi and z component
 m = np.sqrt(r**2. + z**2.) >= 1.

 bx = lambda r_p: self.BX0 * np.exp(-r_p / self.rX) # eq.7
 thetaX = lambda r,z,r_p: np.arctan(np.abs(z)/(r - r_p)) # eq.10

 r_p = r[m] *self.rXc/(self.rXc + np.abs(z[m] ) / np.tan(self.ThetaX0)) # eq 9

 m_r_b = r_p > self.rXc # region with constant elevation angle
 m_r_l = r_p <= self.rXc # region with varying elevation angle

 theta = np.zeros(z[m].shape[0])
 b     = np.zeros(z[m].shape[0])

 r_p0 = (r[m])[m_r_b]  - np.abs( (z[m])[m_r_b] ) / np.tan(self.ThetaX0) # eq.8
 b[m_r_b] = bx(r_p0) * r_p0/ (r[m])[m_r_b] # the field strength in the constant elevation angle (b_x(r_p)r_p/r)
 theta[m_r_b] = self.ThetaX0 * np.ones(theta.shape[0])[m_r_b]

 b[m_r_l] = bx(r_p[m_r_l]) * (r_p[m_r_l]/(r[m])[m_r_l] )**2. # the field strength with varying elevation angle (b_x(r_p)(r_p/r)**2)
 theta[m_r_l] = thetaX((r[m])[m_r_l] ,(z[m])[m_r_l] ,r_p[m_r_l])
 
 mz = (z[m] == 0.)
 theta[mz] = np.pi/2.

 BX[0,m] = b * (np.cos(theta) * (z[m] >= 0) + np.cos(pi*np.ones(theta.shape[0]) - theta) * (z[m] < 0))
 BX[2,m] = b * (np.sin(theta) * (z[m] >= 0) + np.sin(pi*np.ones(theta.shape[0]) - theta) * (z[m] < 0))

 return BX, np.sqrt(np.sum(BX**2.,axis=0))
```

then, I create three arrays, one for r, one for phi, one for z. Each of these arrays has (e.g: thousand elements). like this:

```python
import gmf  
gmfm = gmf.GMF()

x = np.linspace(-20.,20.,100)  
y = np.linspace(-20.,20.,100)
z = np.linspace(-1.,1.,x.shape[0])
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
rr  = np.sqrt(xx**2. + yy**2.)
theta  = np.arctan2(yy,xx)

for i,r in enumerate(rr[:]): 
 Bdisk, Babs_d = gmfm.Bdisk(r,theta[i],z)
 Bhalo, Babs_h = gmfm.Bhalo(r,z)
 BX, Babs_x = gmfm.BX(r,z)

Btotal = Bdisk + Bhalo + BX
```

but I am getting when I make the addition of the three functions Btotal= Bdisk + Bhalo+BX) in 2d matrix with 3 rows and 100 columns.

My question is how can I add these three functions together to get Btotal in shape (n,) e.g( shape(100,)
because as I said in the beginning the three functions accept accept arrays (e.g. shape (1000) )then when we adding the three functions together we have to get the total also in the same shape (shape (n,)?
I do not know how can I do it, could you please tell me how can I make it.
thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: What does adding functions mean? Do you want to add the return values in some way? It will help a lot if you give a specific example with a few, like 3 or 4 entries in each array.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: something like zip(bdisk, bhalo, bx)?

Comment: Make up some dummy values for bdisk, bhalo and bx, of length 10, and then print what the output should be.

Comment: @code-Apprentice I added the description for every thing in the  code above, these 3 function describe the magnetic field in the galaxy, I want to calculate the total magnetic field in the galaxy for that I want to add them !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the indention, for example in the `def Bdisk` method.

More importantly in

```
for i,r in enumerate(rr[:]): 
 Bdisk, Babs_d = gmfm.Bdisk(r,theta[i],z)
 Bhalo, Babs_h = gmfm.Bhalo(r,z)
 BX, Babs_x = gmfm.BX(r,z)

Btotal = Bdisk + Bhalo + BX
```

are you doing this addition for each iteration, or once at the end of the loop?  You aren't accumulating any values over iterations.  You are just throwing away the old ones, leaving you with the final iteration.

As for adding the array - it appears that all your arrays are initialed like:

```
Bdisk = np.zeros((3,r.shape[0]))
```

If that's what the method returns, then

```
Bdisk + Bhalo + BX
```

will just sum the corresponding elements of each array, resulting in a `Btotal` with the same shape. If you don't not like the shape of `Btotal` then change how `Bdisk` is calculated, because it has the same shape.

Comment: yes indeed I want the last iteration( Because I want to where the particle is in the galaxy (final position of the particle in (x,y,z)in the galaxy). you also right the total appears in shape(3,n), BUT I dont want it in this shape. How can I make it in shape (3,)?, OR how can I add the functions together in another way to get the shape (3,)?

Comment: you mean I have to remove      Bdisk = np.zeros((3,r.shape[0]))                to change the shape?